# How to make a DialogFragment change text in activity main?

Tags: java, android-studio

I'm a beginner in Android Studio and Java, and I'm building an app, which contains a dialog, built using DialogFragment. Here's the code for dialog.java:

```
package com.dkapps.shownamenow;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDialogFragment;


public class datatype1 extends AppCompatDialogFragment {
String type = "";
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setNeutralButton("Regular Fraction", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            type = "frac";
            }
        });
        builder.setNeutralButton("Whole Number", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            type = "whole";
            }
        });
        builder.setNeutralButton("Mixed Fraction", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            type = "mixed";
            }
        });
        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

Now, I have a textview in my activity_main with the id 'type'. I want this dialog to set the text of that textview to the value of the string type. How do I do that?

I'd be grateful if you'd provide me some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a method inside your activity to change the TextView's content, and call it in each of the buttons onClick methods.
Here is a code sample:

```
// inside you activity
public setText(String text){
    findViewById(R.id.type).setText(text);
}


// onClick methods
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    ((MainActivity)getActivity()).setText("whole")
    // change "whole" with the value of the string suitable for each button
}
```

You can get rid of the variable type, if you do not need it elsewhere

Answer (score 1):

You could get the textView of your activity with findViewById()

```
private TextView typeFromActivity;    

public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ...

    typeFromActivity = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.type);

    type = typeFromActivity.getText().toString();

    ...        

    return builder.create();
}
```

Comment: I tried that, but findViewById is being highlighted with red and not being accepted.